# Add page to browser history before load finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, back, browser-history

A website I'm working with often loads very slowly.

If you click on a new page before the first page loads, it won't get stored in the browser history, so you can't go back to it with the back button.

So if you go **Google -> My Homepage -> My Page2 -> browser back button** you end up back on Google.

I tried to manually replace the history by calling

```
history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.href)
```

as close to the top of the page as possible, but it doesn't fix the problem in Safari (it seems to in Chrome)

Any ideas of what else could work?

(I realize the ideal solution is the page wouldn't load so slow, but I'm looking for a band-aid for now)

Answer (score 0):

Go Back

`function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}`

history.back() will help you in loading previous page.

Comment: I don't want to load the previous page, I want my users to be able to when they press their browser back button. This has the same functionality as pressing the back button, which doesn't help if the previous page was never stored in history